# Access Build Directory On GitHub

Tags: javascript, github, openlayers-3

I am new to GitHub but am trying to learn. I have been trying to work with the OpenLayers 3 project, or at least use it and test it. When I go to look at historical builds, I see many of them and they are building in a directory called /build. This directory, however, is inaccessible from GitHub. I can't locate the final compiled javascript file. I have created an account and downloaded the desktop app, cloned the repository, but cannot get to a place where I can build it and access the compiled .js file. Can anyone please instruct me how to build the repository into the final js file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options available to you.

- Firstly, if you just want to use the OpenLayers v3 library, you could use the online ol3 library, by using the following two lines in your html:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ol3js.org/en/master/build/ol.css" type="text/css">

<script src="http://ol3js.org/en/master/build/ol.js"></script>`

- If you want to learn how to build your application using self hosted or offline OL3 library, just clone the complete repository, and then use the normal de-minified source file present in `\src\ol` folder.
- And Finally, you can always build your own build version, using the `build.py` given in the repository.

Comment: The problem is the already built ol.js library doesn't have much of the code that is on GitHub. For example, all the code for adding features to layers is on GitHub, but it isn't on the ol.js alpha release. Unfortunately, I do not know how to use the build.py file. I am windows :(. Sorry. Thanks!

Comment: You should have python installed. After that just run `<path to python.exe> build.py` on the command line. This build.py is present in the source code.

Comment: Thanks. So I downloaded python, and I also downloaded OL3 from GitHub. I then went to the command line, went to the ol3 directory, then typed python build.py and got a "syntax error on line 732 of build.py." Hmmmmm.....

Comment: After more investigation, I've found that building OL3 on windows is no easy task. See this page for complete details: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/wiki/Developer-Guide

Comment: So I decided to try your 2nd method. After cloning the repository to my local machine I went into the src/ol directory. Unfortunately, I still cannot find the deminified combined source file. Thanks.